# How do I go about computing the distance between a point and a line in 4-D?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

The point p = (1,1,1,1) ∈ R^4 (real numbers) to the line L(a) with a = (1,2,3,4) in particular. I tried it as follows:

The distance d(p,L(a)) is the orthogonal projection of p onto L(a). So the dot product equals zero. Out of this follows

L(a) = c * a , with c = (c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4) and c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4 elements in the real numbers
Then

dot product of c*a,p = 0, so

1c_1 + 2c_2 + 3c_3 + 4c_4 = 0

and I'm getting stuck here and to be honest I feel like I'm going about this all wrong...  I hope someone can give me a hint or a push in the right direction. Thank you kindly for your time.

Edit:

I think I found the solution:
I'm looking for a vector v_2 that is the orthogonal projection of p onto L(a)
take c = dotprod(a,p)/dotprod(a,a) = 10/30 = 1/3

v_1 = c*a = 1/3 * (1,2,3,4)

v_2 = v - v_1 = (1,1,1,1) - 1/3* (1,2,3,4) = (-2/3, -1/3, 0, 1/3)

The displacement of v_2 = |v_2| = 1/5 sqrt((-2/3)^2 + (-1/3)^2 + (0)^2 + (1/3)^2) and v_2 = d(p,L(a))

am I close?

Comment: One way is to write the distance between p and a point on L as a function of a, and then minimize over all a.

Comment: All you're doing is finding a vector orthogonal to $\vec {Op}$.  I'm not sure why you think that's how to find the distance between the point and the line.

Comment: I'm trying to find the vector through p and orthogonal to the line of a, L(a). So the dot product of any element in L(a) and this new vector p' has to be zero. I really don't know how to move on from that...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the formula for projection. See definition 1.1 of
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line

Comment: But if I take the dot product of p = (1,1,1,1) and a = (1,2,3,4) and divide that by the dot product of a with itself I just get 1/3 * a = (1/3 , 2/3 , 1, 4/3). Is the distance then the absolute value of this new vector?

Comment: The distance is the length of that vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in exactly the same way as in 2 dimensions: find the point $b$ on the line so that $b-a$ is perpendicular to the line. Let the line be $\{ct+d:t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then if $b=ct+d$, this says $t$ has to satisfy
$$ 0=c \cdot (b-a)= c \cdot (ct+d-a), $$
so
$$ t = -\frac{c \cdot(d-a)}{\lVert c \rVert^2}, $$
so
$$ b = d-\frac{c \cdot(d-a)}{\lVert c \rVert^2}c, $$
and
$$ \lVert b-a \rVert^2 = \lVert d-a \rVert^2 - \frac{(c \cdot (d-a))^2}{\lVert c \rVert^2} $$

Comment: I tried to solve this problem in 4D in similar fashion, but if I try finding a z (element of L(a)) so that z-p is an element of L(a)-perp I end up with: 
a = (1,2,3,4)

L(a) = t_1 + 2t_2 + 3t_3 + 4t_4
so if z is a point on the line, at some point :

z = t_1 + 2t_2 + 3t_3 + 4t_4

,I really don't understand how I should continu from this point.

Comment: I think you might be confused about the nature of the definition of a line in four dimensions: a line through $d$ parallel to $c$ is a set of points $\{ c+dt : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$, whatever dimensions the vectors $c,d$ are in.